# SSRS sort not working

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

On a number of reports I have noticed that setting sort options through the tablix properties does not work. I choose the data I'd like to sort by (date) and set the option (Z to A), but the report still shows unsorted. Has anyone else seen this issue? I have read that updating the report xml to include the sort may be what needs to be done because the report builder does not preserve the changes made. Haven't gone down that road yet as I'm looking to see if there's a fix already identified.

```
Date Type Lead Name State distance Consultant ZIP State 1 Level Reason url
```

Those are the columns from the export with data filling each column. Can't give too much info because it shows phone numbers and addresses.

Comment: Is that column datetime type? Share sample data and grouping settings.

Comment: The column is datetime. In terms of grouping, all subtotaling and grouping is unchecked during report creation. I made it to show raw data from the query.

Comment: Group Sorting takes precedence over table sorting which takes precedence over dataset sorting... Are you sure that you are not also sorting by your group or detail levels? Also if your date is **always** a date, try converting it to a date with **CDATE()**.

Comment: I was unsure of grouping settings until I did some digging. I changed the grouping settings and set the sort up there. Now my reports are sorting as needed. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to sort the data in your dataset. Then you can leave it and SSRS will honor that.

As the others mentioned, make sure you check the datatype so it's not trying to sort the dates as a string.

Set the sort priorities at the **group** level, not on the table or dataset properties.

You should never have to edit the XML to get this to work. This is a basic built-in feature that most reports use.

Comment: So I've added an order by in multiple SSRS report queries, but SSRS never honors it.

Comment: Was adding sorts at all levels (data already sorted in the dax).  Nothing was working so removed all the sorts and now works!

Answer (score 4):

Do you have groups on your tablix? if yes, did you try sorting it with the Row Groups or Column Groups at bottom instead of the sorting properties of the tablix?

Comment: I do have groups and I did try sorting using those unsuccessfully.

Comment: do you use matrix or tablix?

Comment: I'm using a tablix in ssrs 2008.

Comment: This is the answer. I did some digging and found how to change sort settings here.

Comment: Everyone's response was pointing to the correct thing, but I could only choose one to mark as the answer. But yes your response pointed me where I needed to go. Thanks.